# elFinder error "Unable to connect to backend. Backend not found."

Tags: php, database-connection, backend, elfinder

I'm starting to work with elFinder and I don't know why but I get this error `"Unable to connect to backend.Backend not found."`. The connector.php looks like this

```
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',           // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path'          => '../files/',                 // path to files (REQUIRED)
            'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'uploadDeny'    => array('all'),                // All Mimetypes not allowed to upload
            'uploadAllow'   => array('image', 'text/plain'),// Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` allowed to upload
            'uploadOrder'   => array('deny', 'allow'),      // allowed Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` only
            'accessControl' => 'access'                     // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        )
    )
);
```

And the path to the file is: myproject >> dashboard >> plugins >> elfinder . What can I do to solve the problem with backend connection?

Answer (score 0):

It is HTTP error "404 Not Found". Please check your connector URL.

Comment: Partial solved now the error is: Invalid backend response.
Data is not JSON.

Comment: Please try elFinder 2.1.15 with connector main option `'debug' => true`.